# Why do rebased commit ids differ from cherry-picked ids?

Tags: git, rebase, cherry-pick

This question stems from a nasty little merge conflict that I got myself into when I accidentally cherry-picked from my tracked branch into my tracking branch as opposed to rebasing it. Fixing it was quite easy, but still trying to wrap my head around why it was an issued in the first place.

Let's say I have the below branches(`tracking` is based off of `tracked`) with series of commits with hash in parentheses, and arrows pointing to parent commits.

`tracked: a(123) <- b(234) <- c(345)`

`tracking: a(123) <- b(234) <- c(345)`

Let's say a new commit `d` with commit id `456` gets into `tracked` so that the state of branches are as below:

`tracked: a(123) <- b(234) <- c(345) <- d(456)`

`tracking: a(123) <- b(234) <- c(345)`

I now `cherry-pick` `456` onto `tracking` leading to the below state of tracking:

`tracking: a(123) <- b(234) <- c(345) <- d(somethingnot456)`

However, if I was to just perform a `git rebase tracked` it would have had been:

`tracking: a(123) <- b(234) <- c(345) <- d(456)`

So why do the ids differ above?

I have seen many questions about `rebase` vs `cherry-pick`, but I haven't managed to come across an answer for this specific question. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the commit ids have a time stamp in them.  The interesting question is whether they're "treesame"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rebase and (repeated) cherry-pick are essentially the same thing, but they're not 100% *exactly* the same thing.  In this particular case, the key is what gets copied, which is, well, nothing at all.

Let me redraw your example the way I prefer to express Git graph fragments.  Instead of:

```
tracked: a(123) <- b(234) <- c(345)

tracking: a(123) <- b(234) <- c(345)
```

let's draw this as:

```
A(123) <- B(234) <- C(345)   <-- tracking, tracked
```

because, after all, each commit is unique: there's only one copy of `A`, one copy of `B`, one of `C`, and soon to be one of `D`.  Meanwhile the two labels (`tracking` and `tracked`) both point to commit `C`, whose hash is `345whatever`.

Now you add your new commit `D(456)` to `tracked` (so `tracking` still points to `C(345)`:

```
A(123) <- B(234) <- C(345)          <-- tracking
                          \
                           D(456)   <-- tracked
```

#### Cherry-pick always copies

What `git cherry-pick <commit>` does is, in essence:

1. diff the given commit against its parent (so, `D` vs `C`)
2. on the current branch (`tracking`), apply the same changes, and
3. make a *new* commit with the same *message*, but different ID.

This is of course just what you've seen before.  Your current branch (`tracking`) acquires new commit `D'`: a copy of `D`, but with a different number.

#### Rebase finds which commits *need* to be copied

Rebase, on the other hand, works by getting a list of all the commits that your current branch (`tracking`) has, that your `<upstream>` branch (`tracked`) does not.  Specifically these are the commits that `git rev-list` will list:

```
$ git rev-list tracked..tracking
$
```

There *are no such commits*, which is easy to see from the drawing.  We don't even need the hashes:

```
A <- B <- C     <-- tracking
           \
            D   <-- tracked
```

Starting from `tracking`, we work our way leftward following the arrows marking commits, but then starting from `tracked` we work our way leftward again following the arrows and *un*marking commits.  Since `D` leads back to `C`, this unmarks everything and we copy nothing at all.

If we had a commit on `tracking` that *wasn't* on tracked:

```
A--B--C--E   <-- tracking
       \
        D    <-- tracked
```

then rebase would copy `E`, making a new (different ID) commit `E'`.  The copy of `E` would go after `D`, like this:

```
A--B--C--E   <-- tracking
       \
        D    <-- tracked
         \
          E' [rebase in progress]
```

#### Then, rebase moves the branch label

Once `git rebase` is done with all its copying, it takes note of where it stopped—at `D`, if there was nothing to copy; at `E'`, or maybe even `F'` or `G'` or whatever if there *were* commits to copy—and then it peels the old branch label (`tracking`) off and pastes it on the new point:

```
A--B--C--E   [abandoned]
       \
        D    <-- tracked
         \
          E' <-- tracking
```

When there's no `E` to copy we get this instead:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- tracked, tracking
```

i.e., both branch labels now point to commit `D`, which was not copied at all.  (There's no reason to keep the little downward leg in the graph either, and there's no commit(s) to abandon—abandoning `E` does not abandon `C`, because `C` is find-able from `D`.)

Answer (score 1):

[`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) will "reapply commits on top of another base tip" while [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) will "apply the changes introduced by some existing commits".

In other words, rebasing will apply *commits* directly on top of your current branch while cherry picking will apply the *changes* from a commit onto your current branch (and then make a new commit).

---

The rebase documentation even says this explicitly after the synopsis:

> If  is specified, *git rebase* will perform an automatic `git checkout <branch>` before doing anything else. Otherwise it remains on the current branch.

So, when using `git rebase tracked`, you essentially just did `git checkout tracked` and fast forwarded your `tracking` branch...